# Spring data rest shows id as path variable in swagger for POST method in mongo repository?

Tags: swagger, spring-data-mongodb, swagger-ui, spring-data-rest, springfox

I am just using MongoRepository. Below is my entity class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "product")
@Data
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Product {

  @Id private String id;

  @Indexed(unique = true)
  private String name;

  private boolean displayAds;
}
```

When I view the resource in Swagger the POST method appears as follows:

[image]

This is my repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;


public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {
}
```

Why does this happen? Is there a fix? I'm using `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui`.

Anyway it can post via Postman without adding such path variable.

Comment: Try adding '@Document' to your model. Also could you post your MongoRepository? Also make sure your controller isn't overriding the end point.

Comment: @"Supun Wijerathne" are you using Springfox by any chance?

Comment: @"Supun Wijerathne" what version of Springfox are you running?

Comment: @NestorLedon 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to **2.8.0** should resolve the issue.

This seems to have been a bug in **Springfox** version **2.7.0**. Should be fixed in **2.8.0** as highlighted [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1839).